# How foreach loop in perl works with arrays in perl

Tags: perl

this program should execute three times but is executing only twice.
Can anyone explain how this foreach loop will work in perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @arr=("sandeepr", "vijay","vikas");
for my $i( @arr)
{
    print @arr;
    my $b=pop(@arr);
    print "\n $b";
}
```

Comment: You are iterating over an array, so you should just `print $i`;  You are also modifying the array you are iterating over, which is generally a bad idea and can cause unexpected results.  Better to copy the array that you wish to manipulate.

Comment: Also, 1-letter variables are in general not a good idea, but specifically in perl, the variables `$a` and `$b` have a special purpose, see perldoc -f sort

Comment: if you want to print the array 3 times, you can:  `for (1..3) { print @arr; }`

Answer (score 11):

[perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops):

> If any part of LIST is an array, `foreach` will get very confused if you add or remove elements within the loop body, for example with `splice`. So don't do that.

As confused as this makes Perl, you appear to be even more confused. What are trying to do? Print the elements in reverse order? If so, you could use

```
for my $ele (reverse @arr) {
   print("$ele\n");
}
```

or

```
for my $i (1..@arr) {
   my $ele = $arr[-$i];
   print("$ele\n");
}
```

or

```
while (@arr) {
   my $ele = pop(@arr);
   print("$ele\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks ikegami for replying. yeah you are correct i am trying to print array in reverse order ( without using inbuilt reverse function though)

Comment: @rawatsandeep1989 what is the purpose of NOT using built-ins for your need? Just to learn how it works or something else?

Comment: @patrick Mevzek ,yes just to learn how it works. :-) what if there were no builtins.